# Split a string by a newline in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this :

> SITE IÇINDE OLMASI\nLÜKS INSAA EDILMIS OLMASI\nSITE IÇINDE YÜZME HAVUZU,
>   VB. SOSYAL YASAM ALANLARININ OLMASI.\nPROJESİNE UYGUN YAPILMIŞ OLMASI

I'm trying to split and save this string like this :

```
array2 = mystring.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var str in sarray2)
{
    if (str != null && str != "")
    {
        _is.RelatedLook.InternalPositive += str;
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This obviously doesn't split my string. How can I split my string in a correct way? Thanks

Comment: Is the `\n` in the input an actual new line or the text "\n"?

Comment: @DavidG It's new line.

Comment: If you have a newline, `s.Split('\n')` will work. See https://ideone.com/Lzj1uU. Also, you may check if a string is null or empty with `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`. However, in your case, I'd even use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Comment: That last line of code in your question will work fine. (though you need to assign the results to an array)

Comment: try string[] wordArray= Regex.Split(your_string, "\\\\n");

Comment: @Developer: Regex does not seem necessary. What you suggest can be achieved with `str.Split(new[] {"\\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`.

Comment: give us the result that you expect

Comment: This is not worth an accepted answer, actually: `myString.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: @DavidG who asked "Is the \n in the input an actual new line or the text "\n"... what's the difference? . the string "\n" is a new line.. a new line is "\n".. what did i miss?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var result = mystring.Split(new string[] {"\\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Since the new line is glued to the words in your case, you have to use an additional back-slash.

Comment: How does this make any difference?

Comment: This is splitting on the string literal "\n" rather than on an actual newline. But that may be what the original poster needs to do.

Comment: do check if your composing email content or just log message, for email, you simply need to use <br> tag |o|

Answer (score 3):

In linqpad I was able to get it split

```
var ug = "SITE IÇINDE OLMASI\nLÜKS INSAA EDILMIS OLMASI\nSITE IÇINDE YÜZME HAVUZU, VB. SOSYAL YASAM ALANLARININ OLMASI.\nPROJESİNE UYGUN YAPILMIŞ OLMASI";
var test = ug.Split('\n');
test.Dump();
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Convert the Literal character sequence for a new line to a string, and split by that - i.e.

```
string clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText();
        string[] seperatingTags = { Environment.NewLine.ToString() };
        List<string> Lines = clipboardText.Split(seperatingTags, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Split by a new line is very tricky since it is not consistent and you can have multiple lines or different combinations of splitting characters. I have tried many methods including some in this thread, but finally, I came up with a solution of my own which seems to fix all the cases I came across.

I am using `Regex.Split` with some cleaning as follows (I have wrapped it in extension method)

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLine(this string str)
{
    return Regex
        .Split(str, @"((\r)+)?(\n)+((\r)+)?")
        .Select(i => i.Trim())
        .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i));
}
```

usage

```
var lines = "string with\nnew lines\r\n\n\n with all kind of weird com\n\r\r\rbinations".SplitByLine();
```